# Can I use curl to test receiving email

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like an automated way to test how my app handles email, with attachments.

Firstly I modified my app (on App Engine) to log the contents of the request body for a received message (as sent through appspotmail). I copied these contents into a file called test_mail.txt

I figured I could post this file to imitate the inbound mail tester, something like so.

```
curl --header "Content-Type:message/rfc822" -X POST -d @test_mail.txt http://localhost:8080/_ah/mail/test@example.com
```

Whenever I do this, the message isn't properly instantiated, and I get an exception when I refer to any of the standard attributes.

Am I missing something in how I am using curl?

I run into the same problem using a simpler email, as posted by _ah/admin/inboundmail

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 15:50:06 +1000
From: test@example.com
To: test@example.com
Subject: Hello
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=cRtRRiD-6434410

--cRtRRiD-6434410
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

There
--cRtRRiD-6434410
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

There
--cRtRRiD-6434410--
```

Comment: "I get an exception" is monumentally unhelpful. What exception? Where is the traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Try `--data-binary` instead of `-d` as the flag for the input file. When I tried with your flags, it looked like curl stripped the carriage returns out of the input file, which meant the MIME parser choked on the POST data.

Answer (score 0):

Black,

I noticed your program is written in python? Why not use twisted to create a tiny smtp client?

Here are a few examples..

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/mail/tutorial/smtpclient/smtpclient.html

Comment: Thanks, but I probably should have been more specific. This is about the appengine dev environment, whereby email reception is emulated by HTTP. I don't think an SMTP client would help.

Comment: Black RGR, still check out other options using twisted as well. It makes creating server and client networked apps very easy, worth a look. (its like sockets on roids)

Comment: And im sure you have thought of this and I apologize for mentioning this but why not urllib2 to make these requests?

Comment: Yeah, twisted is cool, I've used it before. But appengine provides some pretty massive benefits as a platform too. It is probably worth my while attempting this with urllib2 too - thanks.